# Application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again

Tags: android

My android app gives the following when I try to run it....

The application OxfordApp has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.

My code is as follows:

```
package oxfordlife.com.android;

public class OxfordApp extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                  this, R.array.array_name, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item );
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );

        Spinner s = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        s.setAdapter(adapter);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

I am populating the spinner from the string.xml file as follows:

```
<string-array name="array_name">
<item>Array Item One</item>
<item>Array Item Two</item>
<item>Array Item Three</item>
</string-array>
```

The app works fine if I dont try to bind the data to the spinner but as soon as I try to populate it the error is thrown. Can anyone see what I may be doing wrong here ??

Comment: @user693670 Is this the main Activity for your app? Can you check and see what exception is thrown in LogCat? You will either need a logcat viewing app or preferably use the one in Eclipse (Window->Show View->Other->Android->LogCat), this is where your phone will output various error messages. If you have more than one emulator/device running you will also need to open the "Devices" view and make sure the appropriate one is selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

In the beginning of your onCreate method, before trying to access spinner1.

Answer (score 0):

An Activity must be start with

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

so, put it in the begining of `onCreate method`